# Hibernate Session Connection Relationship

Tags: java, database, hibernate

How many connection will hold for a single hibernate session where there is only one DB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At a given time given session will only hold one connection
 which you can access with the [connect](http://ajava.org/online/hibernate3api/org/hibernate/Session.html#connection())() method.

The connection used can be changed though using the [reconnect](http://ajava.org/online/hibernate3api/org/hibernate/Session.html#reconnect(java.sql.Connection))() method.

Comment: thanks for your fast reply, and can a single session hold  more than one connection for more than one DB?

Comment: No, a session can only hold a single connection.

Comment: @objects, and can a single connection used by more than one session?

Answer (score 5):

- there is one connection per session.
- the connection is opened only if the session needs to send JDBC queries
- you should avoid using the underlying connection. The `connection()` method has been deprecated. If you need to perform raw jdbc operations, use the [`doWork(..)`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/api/org/hibernate/Session.html#doWork%28org.hibernate.jdbc.Work%29) method (if your hibernate version is the latest)

Comment: i don't understand the relation between session and connection when closing.First of all we have this affectation : 
`connection = session.connection();` 
In fact in the finally part of try/catch block, how the two methods differ : `session.close()` and `connection.close()` is they do the same role ?

Comment: session.close() closes the underlying connection.

Comment: So there is no sense in calling `connection.close();` once we have called `session.close();`?

Comment: yup. normally you don't even have the connection object